# sqlalchemy filter on date + offset

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

what I try to do is to create a query that finds all records where a date is greater than today - days_before_activation.

For this I use a @hybrid_property that shows the correct start_day (today - days_before_activation).

The issue is, that timedelta does not work in filter queries, at least with sqllite.
Error:

> E       TypeError: unsupported type for timedelta days component:
> InstrumentedAttribute

For this I created an additional column expression (@start.expression). To add the days using plain sql. Unfortunately it does not work when I use the cls.days_before_activation value as part of the expression. The result is always None. However, when I hardcode the integer value it does work. So it looks like I'm doing something wrong with using the value of the property as part of the expression.

Not Working:

```
@start.expression
def start(cls):
   return func.date(datetime.today(), f'+{cls.days_before_activation} days')
```

Working:

```
@start.expression
def start(cls):
   return func.date(datetime.today(), '+ 10 days')
```

Any help are much appreciated.

```
class DefPayoutOffer(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'def_payout_option_offer'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    visual_text = db.Column(db.String(1000), unique=False, nullable=False)
    days_before_activation = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=True)

    @hybrid_property
    def start(self):
        return datetime.today() - timedelta(days=self.days_before_activation)

    @start.expression
    def start(cls):
        return func.date(datetime.today(), f'+{cls.days_before_activation} days')

Query:

    DefPayoutOffer.query.filter(DefPayoutOffer.start > created_date).all()
```

UPDATE:

After finding the solution with the help of python_user.
I had the challenge to make it work for different dialects.

For this I had to move away from the column expression approach to creating a expression.FunctionElement. Advantage is that it can be made dialect specific.

```
class StartCheck(expression.FunctionElement):
        name = 'start_check'
        inherit_cache = True
    
@compiles(StartCheck, 'otherDialect')
    def compile(element, compiler, **kw):
        return "foo"
    
@compiles(StartCheck, 'sqlite')
    def compile(element, compiler, **kw):
        return compiler.process(func.date('now', '+' + expression.cast(list(element.clauses)[0], Unicode) + ' days'))



DefPayoutOffer.query.filter(StartCheck(DefPayoutOffer.days_before_activation) >= date.today()).first()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `expression.cast` with `types.Unicode` to get what you want.

In addition to what you have, you need these imports and then change `start.expression` like so

```
from sqlalchemy.types import Unicode
from sqlalchemy.sql import expression
```

```
@start.expression
def start(cls):
    return func.date('now', '+' + expression.cast(cls.days_before_activation, Unicode) + ' days')
```

Also as a side note, you can use `date('now')` to get the current date, you do not have to use `datetime.today()` like you have shown.

PS: 999 rep, enjoy 1k+ with that upvote

Edit: To select based on dialect, sqlite / postgres

If you have access to `engine` that is used by the session you can use this

```
@start.expression
def start(cls):
    if engine.dialect.name == 'sqlite':
        return func.date('now', '+' + cast(cls.days_before_activation, Unicode) + ' days')
    elif engine.dialect.name == 'postgresql':
        return func.current_date() + cls.days_before_activation
```

Comment: glad it worked @shalama, just a nitpick, in your hybrid_property you are returning a `datetime`, but in the expression you are returning a date, you might want to check that if that is intended or not

Comment: I will check that. One other challenge is that this code is supposed to run on two different databases (Sqlite/Postgres). Postgres will obviously not work because it does use dateadd instead. Do you know if it is possible to use different expressions based on the dialect?

Comment: @shalama see edit, I am not sure if there are better ways but that looks like it should work, this is assuming you have access to `engine` in module level

Comment: I use this approach already for writing dialect specific migrations. What is somehow ok because you run them only once. Calling the if on every query is something i'd like to avoid. But so far I haven't found any other option.

Comment: found a solution for dialect specific implementation. Added to the quest.

Comment: that is a clean solution indeed @shalama, I had no idea such a thing existed in sqlalchemy, the [docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/functions.html#sqlalchemy.sql.functions.FunctionElement) does not tell me anything on how to use that, do you mind linking me wherever you found how to use that and `compiles`

Comment: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/compiler.html